# How can I set my default calendar when done is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, ekcalendar

I want the user to be able to chose a new default calendar with the EKCalendarChooser. 
So far this is what I thought that might work but it is not.

```
   func calendarChooserDidFinish(_ calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser) {
    print("Done was pressed")
    // Set to default calendar
    eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
    for source in eventStore.sources {
        if source.sourceType == .local {
            calendar.source = source
            break
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I set a new default calendar with the EKCalendarChooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //get your calendar if it was previously created
    let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
    for c in calendars
    {
        if c.title == "calendarName"
        {
            calendar = c
        }
    }

//create it if it was not created previously
    if calendar == nil
    {
        let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
        calendar.title = "calendarName"
        if eventStore.sources.count == 0
        {
            calendar.source = EKSource()
        }
        else
        {
            self.setStoreForCalendar(calendar: calendar, store: eventStore)
        }
        do
        {
            try eventStore.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true)
        }
        catch let err as NSError
        {
            print ("error  \(err.description)")
        }
    }

//set defaultCalendar 
    func setStoreForCalendar(calendar:EKCalendar, store:EKEventStore)
    {
        var mSource:EKSource?
        for source in store.sources
        {
            if source.sourceType == .calDAV && source.title == "iCloud"
            {
                mSource = source
            }
        }

        if mSource == nil
        {
            // saving on the local calendar
            mSource = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents?.source
        }
    }
```